# How to call preprocess functions from my custom module

Tags: 8, entities

I have created a custom module that declares a custom image formatter. Now I need to call the Core image module preprocess function 'template_preprocess_image_formatter'. How would I do that?

I tried to add it in the list of preprocess functions of my custom theme but it doesn't fire unless I clear the cache:

```
 /**
  * Implements hook_theme().
  */
 function foo_theme() {
    'image_formatter_foo' => [
          'variables' => ['item' => NULL, 'item_attributes' => NULL, 'image_style' => NULL],
          'file' => 'foo.field.inc',
          'preprocess functions' => [
             'template_preprocess_image',
             'template_preprocess_image_formatter_foo'
          ]
    ],
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [template_preprocess_image_formatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21image.field.inc/function/template_preprocess_image_formatter/8.4.x), I would try the following code below.

Replace mymodule with the machine name of the module. This assume foo is the machine name of your image formatter.

```
mymodule_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  /* processing logic */
}

mymodule_preprocess_image_formatter_foo(&$variables) {
  /* processing logic */
}
```

I also recommend reviewing [Drupal 8's Core Image module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/image) as it has some of the files that call the hooks you need.

1. [image.field.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21image.field.inc/8.4.x) contains template_preprocess_image_formatter
2. [template_preprocess_image](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_image/8.3.x)

Comment: @EricMorand did the answer work for you? If not let me know so i can make any edits to help resolve the issue.